# How to convert str into an int?

Tags: python, integer

I'm trying to make this code turn the prodname variable into an int value:

```
def prod_check(dirname):
    prodname_to_prodnum = {}
    fid2 = open('sample.txt','r')
    line = fid2.readline()
    line = line.strip()
    pline = line.split(',')
    prodname = (pline[0])[1:-1]
    prodnum = prodname
    prodname_to_prodnum[prodname] = prodnum
    line = fid2.readline()
    fid2.close()
```

but when I used "int(prodname)" I get an error

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to do `int(prodname)` and what is the value of `prodname`?

Comment: aaaand what's the error?

Comment: trying to make to integer where it says "prodnum=prodname" but like i said I tried "int()" but no luck.  The error is "Value error: invalid literal for int<> with vase 10: 'James Sakolov'" Prodname is a string of a number.

Comment: *blink* .. what number would you like "James Sakolov" to become?  `prodname` isn't a string of a number, it's apparently a string of a name.

Comment: @Larson "Prodname is a string of a number" -- is it guaranteed to be an integer?  or could it be a string like "15.0" ?  If that's the case then you'll need `int(float(prodname))`

Comment: It looks like you are processing csv data. Maybe you should use the csv module?

Comment: that was my mistake with that name its actually numbers "1,2,3,4,..." random order. But the number format is always between 1-999

Comment: So it is a string containing lots of numbers?  Then you want `map(int,prodname.split(','))`

Comment: What it is are lines being pulled from a file as you see, the format for them is:    #,"Name","Last", "Name", "Date", I pull the first value from it and want it as an integer.

Comment: maybe you want `pline[0]` then?

Comment: yes that was a typo sorry to confuse you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of `prodnum = prodname`:

```
try:
  prodnum = int(prodname)
except ValueError:
  prodnum = None
  print('prodname = ',prodname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists in Python are 0-based, not 1-based. You've already broken the line into fields with `split`, so you should use `prodnum = int(pline[0])` to get the first field.

Edit: I wish people would use copy/paste to put their code into the question, typos make all the difference.

I don't know why you're removing the first and last character from the number field, perhaps because you need to strip blanks from it? If so, try using `prodnum = int(pline[0].strip())`.